# How to filter contour by brightness

Tags: java, opencv, android-studio

i started using opencv a few weeks ago. i would like to know if there is a function for finding out the brightest contour from a List of contours and drawing on the brightest.  so far i managed to convert greyscale, threshold the image and using the findContour functions to find all the whole contours in the image.

tried using the minMax function but can't find how its used in java.

```
 public void process(Mat rgbaImage) {    
        Imgproc.threshold(rgbaImage,rgbaImage,230,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);    
        Imgproc.findContours(rgbaImage,contours,mHierarchy,Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

       /* for(int id = 0; id < contours.size();id++) {

            double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(id));
            if (area > 8000){
                Log.i(TAG1, "contents founds at id" + id);
            }    

        } */   

    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "brightest" means the average color that is brightest, you can use cv::mean(Mat src, Mat mask).
Sadly I only know C++ OpenCV implementation, but I think Java version is almost the same as C++ one.

**C++ Example:**

```
Mat src;  // This is your src image
vector<vector<Point>> contours;   // This is your array of contours

findContours(src.clone(), contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); // Find the contours in the image

int brightestIdx = -1;
int brightestColor = -1;
for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    // First, make a mask image of each contour
    Mat mask(src.cols, src.rows, CV_8U, Scalar(0));
    drawContours(mask, contours, i, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

    // Second, calculate average brightness with mask
    Scalar m = mean(src, mask);

    // Finally, compare current average with previous one
    if(m[0] > brightestColor)
    {
        brightestColor = m[0];
        brightestIdx = i;
    }
}

// Now you've found the brightest index.
// Do whatever you want.

Mat brightest_only(src.cols, src.rows, CV_8U, Scalar(0));
drawContours(brightest_only, contours, brightestIdx, Scalar(255), 1);
```